# How do i build/compile a vue component to be used at runtime with vue?

Tags: vue.js

I have a small component https://github.com/pksorensen/vue-library-build-issue

```
import Vue, { VNode } from 'vue';
import * as tsx from "vue-tsx-support";
import { Component, Prop, Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator';


interface FormAttributes {

}


@Component({
    name: "test"
})
export default class Form extends tsx.Component<FormAttributes>{

    render() {
        return <div>Hello world</div>;
    }
}
```

in a project that I build with `vue-cli-service build --target lib --name mylib src/index.ts`

that produces 'mylib.common.js' and 'mylib.umd.js'.

Now in a static website host, I host an index.html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>dynamicvue</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="/mylib.umd.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        new Vue({
         el:"#app",
            render(h) {
                return h("div","hello world")
            }
        })

        console.log(window.mylib); //this is just a object with nothing in it other than {__esModule:true, __proto__} ect

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

but I cant figure out how I could make Vue render that component at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting `<mylib></mylib>` in the body?